# How do I send a kinesisEvent failure from Lambda to SQS in .NetCore

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I am trying to set up a Kinesis -> Lambda workflow where error retries are handled by a SQS queue with an attached Dead Letter Queue. My idea is to have the lambda function push failed kinesis events to sqs, have sqs retry by pushing to another lambda function and if the retry fails push the message to a SQS Dead Letter Queue.

I have run into a roadblock, specifically, with getting the KinesisEvent object serialized into a string that I can send as a message.

Any help with this is appreciated. I am also open to other ways to do this if my plan does not follow best practice.

```
JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
var amazonSQSClient = new AmazonSQSClient();
SendMessageRequest sendMessageRequest = new SendMessageRequest();
sendMessageRequest.QueueUrl = "someQueueURL";
sendMessageRequest.MessageBody = ToJSONString(kinesisEvent);

await amazonSQSClient.SendMessageAsync(sendMessageRequest);
```

ToJSONString code:

```
private static string ToJSONString(object obj)

{
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
        ser.WriteObject(stream, obj);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

The code returns a "timeouts are not supported on this stream" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sendMessageRequest.MessageBody`could only hold 256kb of data. Therefore it's not a good idea to save the KinesisEvent as a Json object. Think of using DynamoDB or S3 in this case.